# Writing files to S3 using spark and scala is extremely slow. What is a better way to optimize this?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

```
df.write.option("header", "false").
          option("quote", null).
          option("delimiter", Delimiter).
          csv(tempPath)
```

When I save 2 KB files, it takes less than 5 seconds to save to S3 but when I try to save large files of about 20GB, it takes more than 1 hour.

Any suggestions to speed up the writing process?

I am using "s3a//" for saving.

UPDATE: When I manipulate the data of size 5 KB and generate 20KB file to store to S3, it takes 8 secs.
When I try to manipulate  the data of size 250MB and generate 20KB file to store to S3 it takes 45 mins.
I am doing a count before saving so it is evaluated by spark before saving.

And it takes the less than a sec when I copy same 20KBB file to S3 using "aws S3 cp" command.

So what is Spark doing that it is slowing down the save process?

Comment: what's the output of `df.rdd.partitions.length` ? That will give you the number of partitions. If it's 1, then spark will just write one file, which is slow.
You can then use `repartition` to break it down into multiple parallel chunks.

Comment: Yes. The number of partitions for a df1  is 1. But, when it saves to S3 there are more than 1 part files generated. And the other df2 has 200 partitions printed and generated and takes more time about 8 mins to save

Answer (score 3):

It's not the write, it's the fact that the output is committed by rename, which is emulated in s3a by a list and a copy and a delete. The more files you have, the more data you have and the longer it takes. That "use algorithm 2" technique makes things slightly faster, but not safe to use because:

### The real problem here isn't visible, but it's that the commit algorithm assumes that the rename() is atomic and reliable, when it isn't. Data may be silently lost

Unless whoever supplies you with the s3 client says otherwise, work against HDFS, copy to S3 after. (EMR S3's connector is safe to use directly)

1. [Spark Cloud Integration](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/docs/cloud-integration.md)
2. Spark summit [talk on spark and object stores](https://spark-summit.org/east-2017/events/spark-and-object-stores-what-you-need-to-know/)

Answer (score 1):

This can happen If number of partition is high. In that case write data into HDFS then copy data using  `hadoop distcp` or use 
 `s3-dist-cp   --src <source-location>   --dest=s3://<bucket-name/<key>`

OR use s3a:// instead of s3://

And  use  fileoutputcommitter version 2  `--conf "spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version=2"`

Comment: never use s3n; the poster was talking about s3a, which is the successor to s3n, as shipped with ASF hadoop

Comment: I agree with you regarding s3n but rest info are valid. I'm not sure why this is down voted.

Comment: because v2 committer relies on a consistent filesystem to implement commitTask, s3 doesn't deliver that consistency, therefore task commit can lose data. You cannot use either of the file output committers to safely commit work directly to s3, so telling people "use v2 its faster" needs to be rephrased as "v2 runs the same risk of losing work as v1, only more quickly"

Answer (score -2):

I don't think that writing to S3 takes long time. Most likely the DataFrame you are writing takes a lot of time to compute. Try saving it to HDFS first. Then you'll be able to copy files to S3 using `hadoop distcp` command.

Comment: It doesn't take much time to write it to my local file system. Also I am doing a count before saving the df so it is forcing it to evaluate before saving.

Answer (score -3):

Two things:
1. used persist after every join and at save forced it to cache and evaluate.

2. used coalesce to reduce the number of partitions.

It worked.

Comment: Could you please clarify these 

 - (1) do you mean you invoked `cache` before writing out the `DataFrame` on `S3`? If yes, Could you provide some possible explanation how that speeds up the write operation?

 - (2) what were the initial no of partitions and to what number did you finally reduce it? Did you also using `partitionBy`, i.e., store the data split into multiple folders on `S3`?

Comment: I added count() to evaluate it. This will only work if you are saving the data. Else if you unpersist it will lose all the generated data. SO use any action and force it to evaluate and cache it so that future steps can use the cached data. Be very careful when using persist with unpersist if that's how you are going to cache.